# Uploading Images, Videos and Zip becomes "Unable to Preview" / "Invalid"

Tags: c++, qt, dropbox

I can't see any similar problem here so this is why I made this topic.

I am making a QT C++ Application using the DropBox Core REST API. I have no problems authenticating, I can upload but the problem is some types are being invalid after uploaded like image files, video files and zips, weird that PDFs and MP3 doesn't get invalid.

[CODE - QT C++ Code for Uploading]

```
// ----- Javascript

var params                      = new Object();
params.url          = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/"+currentPath+"/"+baseFileName+"?access_token=" + dropboxAccessToken
params.filename         = fileName;
params.basefilename     = baseFileName;
params.endpoint         = "dropboxUpload";
uploader.uploadDropBox(params);

// ----- CPP

QVariantMap paramsMap   = params.toMap();

const QString endpoint      = paramsMap.value("endpoint").toString();
const QString filename      = paramsMap.value("filename").toString();
const QString basefilename  = paramsMap.value("basefilename").toString();
const QString theurl        = paramsMap.value("url").toString();

QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart();

QHttpPart filePart;
QFile *file = new QFile(filename);
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
file->setParent(multiPart);
multiPart->append(filePart);

QUrl urlQuery(theurl);
QNetworkRequest request(urlQuery);

QNetworkReply *reply = networkAccessManager.post(request, multiPart);
reply->setProperty("endpoint", endpoint);
multiPart->setParent(reply);
connect (reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onComplete()));
```

[IMAGE - Highlighted are the files that are fine, rest are invalid files when opened]
[image]

[IMAGE - Unable to Preview]
[image]

[IMAGE - PDF file successfully opened without problems]
[image]

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem

```
QVariantMap paramsMap   = params.toMap();

const QString endpoint      = paramsMap.value("endpoint").toString();
const QString filename      = paramsMap.value("filename").toString();
const QString basefilename  = paramsMap.value("basefilename").toString();
const QString theurl        = paramsMap.value("url").toString();

QHttpPart filePart;
QFile *file = new QFile(filename);
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

QUrl urlQuery(theurl);
QNetworkRequest request(urlQuery);

QNetworkReply *reply = networkAccessManager.put(request, file->readAll());
reply->setProperty("endpoint", endpoint);
connect (reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onComplete()));
```